# UV Problems in Bender

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to map a LEGO Decal onto many faces at the same time
Is there anyway to turn a UV map that looks something like this

[image]

to this without manually tweaking every single vertex?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the Reset button, it should unwrap each face to the full image [image]

Comment: Yes! Thankyou Josip Kladarić, worked like a charm 
Thankyou a lot